# how to create an array from many records in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Since I am new to bigquery, I am struggling with basic stuffs. The table contains 145 records. How to create array from the table. Here is the downloadable link https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1SvkAN8sqS7WnsBO-X3UnyXI8sen5TOZ0 . The downloadable file is in csv format. I would like to know highest marks of each student and their subject.

Comment: what you have tried so far. show us and we can help! and btw, not clear what is expected output  - provide example please! Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this query and it worked.

```
WITH data AS (SELECT DISTINCT name, Physics, Chemistry, Maths, Biology
  FROM `[Your_Project].[Your_dataset].[Your_table]`)
SELECT
  name,
  (CASE
  WHEN Physics >= Chemistry AND Physics >= Maths AND Physics >= Biology THEN Physics
  WHEN Chemistry >= Physics  AND Chemistry >= Maths AND Chemistry >= Biology THEN Chemistry
  WHEN Maths >= Physics AND Maths >= Chemistry AND Maths >= Biology THEN Maths
  WHEN Biology >= Physics AND Biology >= Chemistry AND Biology >= Maths THEN Biology
  ELSE Physics
  END) AS maxmark, 
  (CASE
   WHEN Physics >= Chemistry AND Physics >= Maths AND Physics >= Biology THEN 'Physics'
   WHEN Chemistry >= Physics  AND Chemistry >= Maths AND Chemistry >= Biology THEN 'Chemistry'
   WHEN Maths >= Physics AND Maths >= Chemistry AND Maths >= Biology THEN 'Maths'
   WHEN Biology >= Physics AND Biology >= Chemistry AND Biology >= Maths THEN 'Biology'
   ELSE 'Physics'
   END) as field
FROM
  data
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Monica's answer I finally got your question :o)

I noticed that data in downloadable link is just bunch of duplicate rows so if dedup them just using simple DISTINCT you end up with just 8 rows. so that part is still not clear

But if to ignore this aspect the way to get the highest mark and respective subject is as below. It answer both questions you asked:

1 - How to create array from the table
 2 - how to get highest marks of each student and their subject

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT name, Physics, Chemistry, Maths, Biology
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
SELECT name, 
  (
    SELECT pair
    FROM UNNEST([STRUCT<highest_mark INT64, subject STRING>
      (Physics, 'Physics'), 
      (Chemistry, 'Chemistry'), 
      (Maths, 'Maths'), 
      (Biology, 'Biology')
    ]) pair
    ORDER BY pair.highest_mark DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ).* 
FROM data
```

If to apply above to table with your data  - below is result

```
Row name    highest_mark    subject  
1   Samuel  96              Maths    
2   David   90              Physics  
3   Mark    90              Physics  
4   John    94              Physics  
5   Mathew  94              Physics  
6   Andrew  97              Physics  
7   James   97              Physics  
8   Peter   98              Chemistry
```

I think this solution is more readable and manageable than using branched CASE WHEN THEN ...

Comment: beautiful, works like a charm. but I have a couple of doubts. 1. what does limit 1 suggests(limit is usually used to reduce records is n't it? here 8 records are displayed.) and 2. what does ) .* suggests?

Comment: The two doubts are clear now.
Here the name of the array is pair. Arranging the pair in descending order for each record, so the subject with highest mark comes first, then limiting by 1, so the first set is selected. ).* is used to display the column names highest_mark and subject.
For example first record:

Samuel --> [(67,'Physics'),(89,'Chemistry'),(96,'Maths'),(67,'Biology')]
--> ORDER BY pair.highest_mark DESC --> [(96,'Maths'),(89,'Chemistry'),(67,'Physics'),(67,'Biology')]  ---> 
LIMIT 1  -->  [(96,'Maths')] is selected  --> ).*  --> highest_mark  subject